# Woocommerce bundled pricing amount

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a jacket product and a pant product with 60 variations each in different colors and sizes.

Some of the colors are more expensive
Lets say a black jacket is $150 and a melange jacket is $200.
And a black pant is $80 and melange pant is $120

Then i have bundled those together so i can choose 1 jacket and 1 pant to get a suit.
Then i can define per-item pricing in percentage.
But what i want is to define a discount amount of lets say $50

So if i choose melange jacket and pant it's $270
And if i choose melange jacket and black pant it's $230
And if i choose black jacket and melange pant it's $220

So no matter what i choose it's always the same amount that's discounted.

Does anybody know a way that this can be done?

Comment: Can you not do that with [Product Bundles](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/)?

Comment: No it is only possible to define a "normal price" fixed, or "per-item pricing" which is defined in percentage.

Comment: You're right, the discount is percentage-based. In that case, I don't really have any advice except that you might want to leave an idea on the [ideas board](http://ideas.woothemes.com/forums/133476-woocommerce) for the author to support value-based discounts.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that i found a way to rewrite some code in the product bundles that makes it possible to define an amount instead of percentage. I made it right in the plugin folder i know that it's very good to do it that way but as for know i really don't know how to do it any other way. I'm going to put the modified code on github under matskruger when i have testet it throughly.

Comment: I'm glad you've found a temporary solution. Could I ask you *not* to put the code up on github? Not publically, anyway. Technically, you can do whatever you like under GPL, but I know the author personally and he puts a tremendous amount of effort into his plugins so it seems like poor form to redistribute his work. Thanks for considering it.

Comment: Also, I would submit a support ticket (their queue is completely ridiculous at the moment), but that is probably even better than the ideas forum for informing the author of your feature request. We both get instant notifications when it concerns out plugins so even if you don't hear back from Woo, he should see it.

Comment: I would only put up the code to change and where to change it. But thanks for the heads up. I will write to the author and request the feature. It's a feature i have been looking for for months and i don't think i'm the only one that could Venedig from it. Thank you for your help

Comment: Appreciate that! Good luck.